# MYSQL Partition avoid full scan table

Tags: mysql, partition

Back ground: I have 8 million records and i want to speed up the Query time this is my table

```
    CREATE TABLE vehiclelog3 (
  ID INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`PNumber` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,

  `Date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,

  `Time` TIME DEFAULT NULL,

  `Offset` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,

  `Street1` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,

  `Street2` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,

`City` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,

  `Region` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
ect...

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`Date`),
  UNIQUE KEY ID (`ID`,`Date`),
  KEY date (`Date`),
  KEY plate (`PNumber`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
PARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(`Date`) )
   PARTITIONS 12;
```

My problem is i want  to avoid full scan to table for example if my query is like

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS Select * from vehiclelog3 where PNumber = "bla" and Date = "2014-01-18"
```

output:

```
 1  SIMPLE       vehiclelog3  p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12  index   (NULL)         PRIMARY  7        (NULL)  3346217  Using where
```

i just want to scan only the partition that have that data. Is it possible?

Comment: I used your `create` and `select`, and the query only touched one partition, as it is supposed to. Could you post a non-truncated version of the create query and a real select query(your select has `plate` column which is a key, not a column in the create)?

Comment: Oh! Sorry for that i edit the plate to PNumber in Select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM tableNmae PARTITION (partitionName); 
as taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html
can be used to restrict SELECT's to only one partition.
So because you know the relation between the partition and the date that you are using, this is trivial.

Comment: i try this `SELECT * FROM vehiclelog3 PARTITION(p1); but i got this error `error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(p1) LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 11`

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is a feature introduced in MySQL 5.6, if you are using a older version this query will fail. So this leads to the question: can you update your MySQL - version?

Comment: awts ok ill try to contact our database web server admin if they can update there mysql. thanks Peter